# How do I call else statement properly in c# unity3d

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine

I just need to call an else statement. The line of code in the if statement I have works . I get an error when I want to do the else statement . I am basically using the same code just with lesser points and timer reaches zero and scene changes. Here is my code :

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections; 
using UnityEngine.UI; 
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour 
{  
    public MyClockScript myClock;  
    public ScoreManagerScript scoremanager;
    public int scoreToReach = 99; // change this value to what you want 
    public int leastscore = 50;  
    public string nextScene = "FY"; // change this value to what you want

    void Update ()   
    { 
        if (myClock.m_leftTime <= 0)  
            {  
                if ((ScoreManagerScript.score >= scoreToReach) && (nextScene != ""))  
                    {  
                         SceneManager.LoadScene(nextScene);  
                    }  
                    else  
                    {  
                        ((ScoreManagerScript.score >= scoreToReach) && nextScene != ""))  
                    }  
            }  
        }       
     }
}
```

Comment: do you mind formatting your posted code and make it readable?

Comment: Your code is completely unreadable.

Comment: They need a statistic for how many people have abandoned the edit.

Comment: your if and else have the same conditions

Answer (score 0):

Changed as a result of edit to original question.  A couple of points, please use the parentheses button ({}) to format code.  Secondly you appear to be wanting to do not an else but an else if; see my correction below.

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections; 
using UnityEngine.UI; 
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    public MyClockScript myClock; 
    public ScoreManagerScript scoremanager; 
    public int scoreToReach = 99; // change this value to what you want 
    public int leastscore = 50; 
    public string nextScene = "FY"; // change this value to what you want

    void Update () 
    { 
        if (myClock.m_leftTime <= 0)  
        {  
            if ((ScoreManagerScript.score >= scoreToReach) && (nextScene != ""))  
            {  
                SceneManager.LoadScene(nextScene);  
            }  
            else if ((ScoreManagerScript.score >= leastscore) && (restartscene != ""))   
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(restartscene);
            }  
        }
        else  
        {       
            ; // put your else (Time expired) code here
        } 
    }
}
```

Also both if statements in revised question seem to be the same??

Comment: His *actual* code didn't have the `=` vs `==` problem. It was actually very distorted formatting due to using `<` without a code block, and some text went missing from the display. Check the edit history carefully to see what I mean.

Comment: Also worth noting that his code does not compile in the first place, so something remains unclear. I wouldn't rush into trying to answer it ^.^

Comment: @SimpleVar Yes There were a couple of changes as I was typing.  I did edit my answer as soon as I saw this.  I answered, because I hoped that a properly formatted answer (not to mention one that had an outside chance of compiling) would push the OP down the right lines!!!

Comment: It's corrects. Have no error . But have problem the scene is only switching on this code :                                 
<pre ><code > void Update () { if (myClock.m_leftTime &lt;= 0) { if ((ScoreManagerScript.score &gt;= scoreToReach) &amp;&amp; (nextScene != "")) { SceneManager.LoadScene(nextScene); } </code></pre>

Comment: It doesn't run the other code : else if ((ScoreManagerScript.score &gt;= leastscore) &amp;&amp; (restartscene != "")) { SceneManager.LoadScene(restartscene); //enter else if code here }

Comment: I trying to do least score like if it a point less than the score reach and timer reach zero.